# How to iterate through html element and capture values for id and value using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I have a situation where data is dynamically being presented on the screen from an ajax/json call to the database.  The data can then be manipulated by the user and is appearing as an li item on the screen.  The data is triggered by a ddl and is dynamic (meaning there are various items that may be displayed based on the ddl selection).  I need to capture the values and id for each item.  I would like to serialize the values and pass to db but I am running into problems doing so.  Please help.

Javascript to build HTML/populate data initially:

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                            form += '<li><input class="number" name="product-item_' + items[i].RiskID + '" id="product-item_' + items[i].RiskID + '" type="text" value="' + items[i].DefaultFee + '" /> ' + items[i].Description + '</li>';

                        }
```

Javascript being called to getInfo and save changes on client side:

```
var getInfo = function () {
                    return {
                        ProductID: $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Manage1_ddlProducts').val(),
                        ProductDescription: $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Manage1_ddlProducts option:selected').text(),
                        ProductItems: $("#ProductItems").html(),
                        //The code below is blowing up:
                        ItemValue: $("#li").each(function (n) { $(this).attr('value'); })
                       //This will also have to be done
                       ItemID: $("#li").each(function (n) { var currId = $(this).attr('id'); var removeTxt = "product-item_"; var currID = currId.replace(removeTxt,""); })
                    };
                };
```

My approach may be flawed. I am open to a modifying my current method.  An example of my desired serialized result is:

```
[{"ProductID": "Xa","ItemID":"Ya1","ItemValue":"Za1","ItemID":"Ya2","ItemValue":"Za2"},
 {"ProductID": "Xb","ItemID":"Yb1","ItemValue":"Zb1"}].
```

(Where Xa, Ya, Za, etc. represent values.)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It looks like you could use knockoutjs. Check out the tutorial for loading and saving data from a json call: http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
ItemValue: $("#li").each(function (n) { $(this).attr('value'); })
```

will return a jQuery object, not an array as I think you're expecting. Try [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) instead:

```
ItemValue: $.map($("#li"),function(el,n) { return $(this).attr('value'); })
```

Alternatively, you can `.join(',')` the array into a single comma-delimited string once it's mapped.

*The conversion of `ItemID`'s mapping function is left as an exercise for the reader.*